# .htaccess point domain to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I have a domain and a subdomain. I need to temporarily point a folder in the domain to the same folder in a subdomain.

Example:
http://www.domain.com/api/ -> http://dev.domain.com/api/

Is there a way to do this with htaccess rewrite rules?

Answer (score 0):

add these directives to your .htaccess (or virtual host config)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ http://dev.domain.com/api/$1 [R=302,NC ]
```